# Chat Bot from Google Sheets Event - Double Function?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks, google-chat

I am trying to have a bot send a message to a chat room based on a FALSE check mark in a specific cell on a sheet.

I have the function working for

1. Timestamp and getEffectiveUser().getEmail - for accountability
2. function sendReminder() - which uses a webhook to send a message to a chat room (stole this one from Google Dev)

Here is the code I have and I have tried many, many variations to call the function sendReminder if e.value == "FALSE" (I understand this is not the ideal method and certainly am open to suggestions)

Here is the code as it stands but the only way it works is manually - Again would like for sendReminder to fire off once the cell has "FALSE" in it.

```js
function onEdit(e){

  if(e.value == "TRUE"){
    e.source.getSheetByName("Daily").getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart+1).setValue(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
    e.source.getSheetByName("Daily").getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart+2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");}
return e.value;
}

function sendReminder(){
var data = {
text: "Looks like LCH Temp is open right now - Can someone take over?"
};
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
var options = {
method: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json',
payload: payload
};
var url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAuBSsspc/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=jqvtFaKqM1a_spMOJFByn29jTEL5iF-JZQ9BEFws9u4%3D'
var rsp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Simple Triggers have restrictions on what type of methods can be run. You will need to change this to an installable trigger.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on Simple Triggers:

> They cannot access [services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services) that require [authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization). For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the [Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail) requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the [Language service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language), which is anonymous.

As `UrlFetchApp` requires authorisation, you will not be able to run this from just a simple trigger.

#### Fix:

You will need to have your checking code inside you `onEdit(e)` for "FALSE", something like:

```js
function whenEdited(e) {
  // whatever code you already have
  // change "C5" on the next line to whatever specific cell you want to check:
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "C5" && e.value == "FALSE") { 
    sendReminder()
  }
}
```

Then, you will need to set up your `whenEdited()` function as an installable trigger:

#### Setting up the Trigger:

Save the script with the save icon, press the run button (►), and confirm the authentication of running the script.

From here, following the `Edit > Current project's triggers` menu item, you will have a new page open in the G Suite Developer Hub. Click the `+ Add Trigger` button in the bottom right and set up the trigger settings as follows:

- Choose which function to run: `whenEdited`
- Choose which deployment should run: Head
- Select event source: From spreadsheet
- Select type of time based trigger: On edit

And press save. Now, whenever the cell you specified is edited, the `sendEmails()` function will run, pre-authorised as you.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)